# Is Isaiah 7 and Isaiah 9 speaking of the same child?

Tags: isaiah, child

In Isaiah 7:14-16

> 14 Therefore the Lord Himself will give you a sign: Behold, the virgin
> will conceive and give birth to a son, and she will name Him Immanuel.
> 15 He will eat curds and honey at the time He knows enough to refuse
> evil and choose good. 16 For before the boy knows enough to refuse
> evil and choose good, the land whose two kings you dread will be
> abandoned.

and in Isaiah 9:6

> For a Child will be born to us, a Son will be given to us; And the
> government will rest on His shoulders; And His name will be called
> Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal Father, Prince of Peace.

Are these passages speaking of the same child?

Comment: Excellent question for people to ponder. Thank you.

Comment: Isaiah 7 and 8 are the same context. In Isaiah 8 "and i went into the prophetess".....hmmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes" and "NO".  Let me be more specific.

**Isa 7:14** is a prophecy about a child that Isaiah's wife would have as a sign that Assyria would be defeated.  It is a local prophecy about a local situation and carries no immediate Messianic overtones.

However, the inspired NT writer, Matthew in ch 1:23 takes this prophecy and re-purposes it to apply to Christ. This could not have been deduced from the original text but by the direction of the Holy Spirit it now has become a Messianic prophecy about Jesus.

**Isa 9:6** - by contrast, the prophecy of Isa 9 is a prophecy about the future - a time when the "great light" would appear (V2, 6, 7).  This is clearly and always was a Messianic prophecy.

**CONCLUSION**

Therefore, originally, the two prophecies of Isa 7:14 & 9:6 were discussing two different children but because the or the NT re-purposing of one of them, they now both point to the same child - the Messiah born in Bethlehem.

Comment: No one in the New Testament applied Isaiah 9:6 to Jesus. The Septuagint translation of Isaiah 9:6 used by Jesus and the Apostles does not support the Roman Catholic corruption of Isaiah 9:6.

Comment: @JesusSaves - are you suggesting the BHS is wrong?  What is the true text and how do you know?  Further, again, do not put words in my mouth - I DID NOT SAY that anyone in the NT applied Isa 9:6 to Jesus!!

Comment: I did not say you claimed that the NT applied Isaiah 9:6 to Jesus. I was pointed out a material fact.